# Get date in format 2016-01-01T00:00:00.000-00:00

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to get a date in this format for [mercadolibre api](http://developers.mercadolibre.com/metrics/#modal1):

```
2016-01-01T00:00:00.000-00:00
```

But when I do:

```
var date_from = new Date();
    date_from.setDate(date_from.getDate() - 1);
    date_from.setUTCHours(0,0,0,0);
```

I get:

```
2017-01-08T17:04:54.925Z
```

How I fix this?

Comment: `new Date(2016,0,1).toISOString().replace("Z","-000")`

Comment: It works for me. You get that result with `date_from.toISOString()`?

Comment: @BrunoLM I get this '2017-01-08T17:17:16.650Z'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both using `setUTCHours(hours, minutes, seconds, ms)` and calling each function individually work. Try running the example bellow and compare to your full code.

```js
var date_from = new Date();
    date_from.setDate(date_from.getDate() - 1);
    date_from.setUTCHours(0,0,0,0);

console.log('example 1', date_from.toISOString());

date_from = new Date();
date_from.setDate(date_from.getDate() - 1);
date_from.setUTCHours(0);
date_from.setUTCMinutes(0);
date_from.setUTCSeconds(0);
date_from.setUTCMilliseconds(0);

console.log('example 2', date_from.toISOString());
```